# best way to use proguard with dwr

Tags: jakarta-ee, obfuscation, dwr

i'm planning to use Proguard to obfuscate a Java EE web application but i wonder if the there's a way to obfuscate DWR calls to java classes since the  class methods won't keep the same name , and this will surely impact my frontend dependencie with the back end.

Answer (score 1):

The DWR caller code cannot be obfuscated because it is auto-generated by internal DWR classes.  Use the [keep options of Proguard to skip obfuscation](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html) of DWR classes/methods that you `<create>` and `<include>` in DWR.xml.  To try and manually obfuscate, you could use different names for the Javascript caller file and the Java class file, e.g.:

```
<create creator="new" scope="request" javascript="AAA">
  <param name="class" value="my.package.BBB">
</create>
```

Usually, AAA and BBB would be named similarly (for code traceability and code readability), but in the above they're deliberately named differently.

Another way to look at this is that you should obfuscate the classes that contain your proprietary logic, and leave the plumbing classes un-obfuscated, which also helps in troubleshooting.

Comment: thanks for the prompt answer .
actualy i'm using DWR with convention and annotations , so i'm trying to -keep annotated remote methods in class with the wildcard *DWR .
what do you think of this solution ?

Comment: I haven't used annotations for my DWR classes, but if you're saying you'll use something like: `@RemoteProxy(name="AAA")`.  Then it looks fine to me.